# No photoelectron is emitted from which of the following metals?

Tags: electricity, photoelectric-effect

So there was this multiple choice question in an exercise in a bookI'm reading. I know that the forum is about discussions. But I want to know what the answer to the question is and why it is so.

From which of the following metals will photoelectrons not be emitted (under normal conditions)?

a. Cesium
b. Potassium
c. Aluminium
d. Sodium

Now, my confusions circle Aluminium and Potassium. Cesium has a work function that is sufficiently low to exhibit photoelectric effect. Aluminium's work function borders on the threshold at just over 4. But in standard conditions Cesium is a fluid. And without a rigid characteristic metal lattice, the photoelectric effect is not going to work, is it? A little help with this would be nice.

Comment: What are "normal conditions"?

Comment: Cesium is still a solid at normal conditions (which are usually defined as between 0 degrees C and 20 degrees C). Cesium has a melting point of 28.4 degrees C and would therefor be solid for any of the differing definitions. Even if it was already liquid it wouldn't matter, the photoelectric effect is not bound to the existence of a crystalline lattice. Liquid photocathodes have been investigate and are occasionally being used according to the literature. If you define the radiation field as being in equilibrium with normal conditions none of these metals will emit photoelectrons.

Comment: What determines the threshold of the work function, which you mention?

Comment: Frankly, this seems to be a terrible question, since it would depend on what the authors of the book think are 'normal' conditions. I would not expect chunks of any of these to be emitting photoelectrons while sitting on my desk at night. In daylight, well that might be a different story. Under a UV lamp is yet another...

Comment: I'm sorry to be ambiguous but this is exactly what the book says. It was written almost 3 decades ago. There's no specification as to what the author means by normal temperature. But as per the varying definitions, even the standard room temperature doesn't cross 25 degrees Celsius. Given that, Cesium isn't liquid at room temp. But this book lists Cesium as one of five elements that are liquid at normal temp. I guess I should simply leave out old stuff and concentrate on better explanations.

Comment: Given that this question does not specify the abverlangt of the light being used, it does not really provide enough information for a conclusive answer.

Comment: Note also that this site is neither a forum (it's a Q&A site) nor is it for discussions (it's for Questions and Answers).

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is justified since the value of the work function depends on the configuration of the atoms in the material, and therefore can vary significantly.

The work function values can be found in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function#Work_functions_of_elements.5B11.5D). I also have the 1975/1976 edition of the *Handbook of Chemistry and Physics* which contains a table of work functions, and separately lists the *thermionic work function* and the *photoelectric work function*.

Here are the values lists in those sources (rounded to the nearest tenth):

```
Element      Wikipedia     CRC Handbook
Sodium          2.4          2.1-2.3
Potassium       2.3          2.0-2.3
Aluminum      4.1-4.3        3.0-4.4  
Cesium          2.1      1.9-2.0  4.1-5.6
```

So if you just go by the Wikipedia values, then clearly aluminum is the answer. But the CRC handbook paints a more ambiguous picture, since the work function for Cesium falls into two ranges, depending on the state of the Cesium. Unfortunately, the CRC handbook doesn't say what conditions are needed for the range `1.9-2.0`.

So Sodium and Potassium are definitely not the answer, Cesium may or may not be the answer depending on what state it's in, and Aluminum always has a high work function. So Aluminum is your best choice for the answer.

---

Allow me to also point out that Sodium, Potassium, and Cesium are all in the leftmost column of the periodic table, and have a single valence electron. It's therefore reasonable to expect that valence electron will behave similarly for all three elements (the photoelectron is almost certainly the outermost electron). Aluminum, on the other hand, has three valence electrons, so it's reasonable to expect it to behave differently.

Comment: The work function varies with the crystal surface; thus the work function s for the (100) and (111) face will typically be different.  This often accounts for the variations given in the tables.

Comment: @PeterDiehr Yes, that's true. The CRC handbook lists 4.86 as the work function for the (111) face and 5.61 for the (100) face. Unfortunately, it doesn't give any clues about the 1.9 to 2.0 range.

Comment: Well I guess this question isn't a very accurate question. It's ambiguous in many senses. So given the work functions, Aluminium is the more reasonable answer.

Comment: @AniruddhaGS Yes, I think that's about all you can say.